# how to create a pdf with no margins using itext?

Tags: java, itext

I am trying to create a pdf using itext and i want there t o be a footer that runs along the very bottom of the page, with no margins or white space underneath of it. I have created a document and set the margins to 0 but not matter what there is still a margin around the edge. Any help would be great! Here is what i have :

```java
public class PageTemplate
{

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {

        Rectangle fullPage  = new Rectangle( 619, 792 );
        fullPage.setBorder( Rectangle.NO_BORDER ); // left, right, top, bottom border
        fullPage.setBorderWidth( 0 ); // a width of 5 user units
        fullPage.setUseVariableBorders( true ); // the full width will be visible

        Document document   = new Document( fullPage, 0, 0, 0, 0 );



        try
        {
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance( document, new FileOutputStream( "results/template2.pdf" ) );

            document.open();

            PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();                      
            cb.setColorFill( new Color( 52, 152, 219 ) );

            BaseFont bfBold   = BaseFont.createFont( BaseFont.HELVETICA_BOLD, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED );
            Font footerFont   = new Font( bfBold, 6 );
            footerFont.setColor( new Color( 255, 255, 255 ) );

            PdfPTable footer  = new PdfPTable( 1 );
            PdfPCell footerCell = new PdfPCell();
            footer.setTotalWidth( 612 );
            footer.getDefaultCell().setBorder( PdfPCell.NO_BORDER );
            footer.getDefaultCell().setHorizontalAlignment( Element.ALIGN_LEFT );
            footer.getDefaultCell().setVerticalAlignment( Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE );
            footer.getDefaultCell().setBackgroundColor( new Color( 52, 152, 219 ) );
            footer.getDefaultCell().setPaddingLeft( 30 );
            footer.addCell( new Phrase( new Chunk( "We need to decide what to put here", footerFont ) ) );
            footer.getRow( 0 ).setMaxHeights( 18 );
            footer.completeRow();

            System.out.println( "Spacing BEFORE table: " + footer.spacingBefore() );
            System.out.println( "Spacing AFTER table: " + footer.spacingAfter() );            
            System.out.println( "Footer table has " + footer.size() + " rows" );

            footer.writeSelectedRows( 0, -1, document.left(), document.bottom() + 18, cb );


            document.newPage();

        }


        catch ( DocumentException de )
        {
            System.err.println( de.getMessage() );
        }

        catch ( IOException ioe )
        {
            System.err.println( ioe.getMessage() );
        }

        document.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify: you are only adding a table at absolute positions in your code snippet. I don't see you adding any other content, which means the zero margins are never used. Isn't there a change that what you perceive as margins is nothing more than the left padding (30) and some remaining space because the cell is 18 user units high and there not sufficient text to fill it? (Also: please set the maximum height at the cell level instead of at the row level.)

Comment: Did you look at the [FullPageTable](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/tables/FullPageTable) example that was written in answer to this question: [How to increase the width of PdfPTable in itext Pdf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19873263/how-to-increase-the-width-of-pdfptable-in-itext-pdf) (if you introduce a table footer, you don't even have to worry about positioning the footer)

Comment: One small warning: printers in general will not print near the page border.

Comment: No functioning links to claimed solutions are of no help.